# XSL:IF/XSL:WHEN XslCompiledTransform test evaluating extension object

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm implementing XSL transformation using the .Net [XslCompiledTransform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform?view=net-5.0)

I'd like to add `xsl:if` or `xsl:when` evaluating method from my [C# extension object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addextensionobject?view=net-5.0)

**Full XSL**

```html
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:myObj="urn:myObj">      
  <xsl:template match="rFactorXML/RaceResults/*">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="myObj:IsElement(name(.))">
        <Custom>
          <SessionType>
            <xsl:value-of select="myObj:Convert(name(.))"/>
          </SessionType>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </Custom>        
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```
public class MyObj
{
    public bool IsElement(string name) => name == "xyz";
    public string Convert(string name) => "ZYX";
}

...
var myObj = new MyObj();
var argsList = new XsltArgumentList();
argsList.AddExtensionObject("urn:myObj", myObj);
// more code as link above C# extension object
...
```

The `xsl:value-of` works well, however, I don't know how to use the myObj for testing IF/WHEN

Running it fails with Exception:

> System.Xml.Xsl.XslLoadException: 'myObj.IsElement()' is an unknown XSLT function.

Any idea how to call extension object functions in `xsl:if`/`xsl:when` test?

**EDIT**
As one of the comments pointed out, I had a typo and instead of

> myObj:IsElement(name(.))

I was trying to call

> myObj.IsElement(name(.))

Problem solved

Comment: You have a typo: it must be `myObj:IsElement(name(.))` using a colon instead of a dot.

Comment: thank you, can't believe such a s...d mistake